# Items without price labels = theft?

Tags: halacha

Is it permissible for a jewish owned store in a jewish neighborhood (for example a supermarket) to not put price tags on items?

My logic is that it may cause embarrassment for a customer to go to the checkout and discover they can not afford certain items.
Secondly, it seems somewhat deceitful to not label items with a price.

Please use proper source citation when answering this question.

Comment: It might also cause people to ask for the price when they weren't planning on making a purchase

Comment: @Dude How could they know if they are planning on making a purchase or not without knowing the price?

Comment: @JoelK not every decision is priced based and there is a problem of genevas daas to ask if you aren't planning on purchasing. This could potentially be an issue if lifne eiver

Comment: What if there isn't a fixed price and it's all up for bargaining?

Comment: For what it's worth this is Minhag haMakom in many stores in Israel

Comment: As long as the price isn’t more than a sixth more than the going regular price for that item it should be permitted

Comment: @Chatzkel what's your reasoning?

Comment: More than a sixth is onah.